# User profile update error

Tags: php, mysql

i am doing a user profile update after user login to the system. Everything is good, after user login, user can change their username pass etc. But there is a problem, when user change their details, it will change the entire user database details.  Here is my coding

Here is the login coding

```
<form class="modal-content animate" action="qcon.php" method="POST">
<div class="imgcontainer">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  <img src="download.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <label><b>Username</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

  <label><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

  <button type="submit">Login</button>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name ="submit"> Remember me
  </div>
```

Here is the connect to database coding

```
 <?php


        $connect = new mysqli("localhost","root","","tenantsdb");

    $submit = isset($_POST['submit']);

    if($submit)
    {
        $uname = $_POST['uname'];
        $psw   = $_POST['psw'];
    }
 $get = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tenantsignup WHERE uname 
 ='$uname' AND psw ='$psw'");
 $get2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get);
 $id = $get2['id'];
 $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

 if($num==1)
 {
    header("location:q1.php?id=$id");
 }

 else
 {
    echo"this username doesnt exsts";
 }
 ?>
```

Here is the page that after user login

```
<div class = "col-md-6">
<div class = "panel panel-default">
    <div class = "panel-body">

    <?php
    global $conn;
    $servername = "localhost";  //host name
    $username = "root"; //username
    $password = ""; //password
    $mysqli_database = "tenantsdb"; //database name

    //mysqli prepared statement 

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, 
    $mysqli_database) or die("Connection failed: " . 
    mysqli_connect_error());

    mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysqli_database) or die("Opps some thing went 
    wrong");
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $sql  = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tenantsignup WHERE id 
    ='$id'");
    $get3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        $uname = $_POST['uname'];
        $psw = $_POST['psw'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $contact_no = $_POST['contact_no'];
        $area = $_POST['area'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $max_budget = $_POST['max_budget'];
        $staying_with = $_POST['staying_with'];
        $race = $_POST['race'];

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE tenantsignup set 
        uname='$uname',psw='$psw',name='$name', 
        email='$email',contact_no='$contact_no',area='$area',
        gender='$gender',age='$age',max_budget='$max_budget',
        staying_with='$staying_with',race='$race'");

        if($result){

        echo 'Success!';

        }else{

        echo 'failed';

        }
    }
    ?>

    <form action ="q1.php" method="POST">
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="id">ID</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?
        php echo $id;?>">
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="uname">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="uname" 
         name="uname"value="<?php echo $uname;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="psw">Password</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="psw" name="psw"value="
        <?php echo $psw;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="name" 
         name="name"value="<?php echo $name;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="email" 
        name="email"value="<?php echo $email;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="contact_no">Contact No</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="contact_no" 
        name="contact_no"value="<?php echo $contact_no;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="area">Area</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="area" 
        name="area"value="<?php echo $area;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="gender">Gender</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="gender" 
        name="gender"value="<?php echo $gender;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="age" name="age"value="
        <?php echo $age;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="max_budget">Max Budget</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="max_budget" 
    name="max_budget"value="<?php echo $max_budget;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="staying_with">Staying With</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="staying_with" 
    name="staying_with" value="<?php echo $staying_with;?>" >
    </div>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for ="race">Race</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" id="race" 
    name="race"value="<?php echo $race;?>" >
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: you need to add where condition in your update query. Do you have id or unique field in user table ?

Comment: your acceptance record is questionable

Comment: `$submit = isset($_POST['submit']);` this will always be considered as being set.

Comment: you're also open to a serious sql injection; don't wait till it's too late to use a prepared statement; you will get hacked and storing plain text passwords. This is a hot recipe for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a WHERE clause to your UPDATE query:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE tenantsignup set 
        uname='$uname',psw='$psw',name='$name', 
        email='$email',contact_no='$contact_no',area='$area',
        gender='$gender',age='$age',max_budget='$max_budget',
        staying_with='$staying_with',race='$race' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: thx, @ChrisD...it is working :) and thx everybody who commend in my post, very appreciate it and i will focus on the sql injection :)...thank you and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **WHERE** with your query.

Replace your query with

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE tenantsignup set 
        uname='$uname',psw='$psw',name='$name', 
        email='$email',contact_no='$contact_no',area='$area',
        gender='$gender',age='$age',max_budget='$max_budget',
        staying_with='$staying_with',race='$race' WHERE id=$id");
```

**Note: Its not a secure way to update data . you should use pdo or prepared statement.**